# cakephp debug info shows up unexpectedly

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, cakephp

the debug info shows up for no reason even if i make default.ctp into a blank html.

e.g.

```
Request History
4 previous requests available
Restore to current request
wp/wp-content/themes/budapest/library/img/icons/map.png
menus/delivery/wp/wp-content/themes/budapest/library/img/icons/map.png
menus/delivery/index.html



Session


+
Session
Config
userAgenteb582f3201bdbd1fba0bd5eda4774240
time1377350192
countdown10

Request
+
Request
Cake Params

plugin(null)
controllerpages
actiondisplay
named(empty)
pass
0home
Post data

No post data.

Query string

No querystring data.

Cookie

To view Cookies, add CookieComponent to Controller

Current Route

keys(empty)
options(empty)...
```

as so on for multiple pages showing me everything like what phpinfo() does in php.
it happened after i try to put a website i got from httrack. now if i disable DebugKit for cake, the page will not display at all. but if i enable DebugKit the page will display alone with all these info i dont want.
can some1 help me with this plz?

here is my code in Default.ctp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IEMobile 7 ]> <html lang="en-US" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:addthis="http://www.addthis.com/help/api-spec"
                            prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"class="no-js iem7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en-US" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:addthis="http://www.addthis.com/help/api-spec"
                         prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en-US" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:addthis="http://www.addthis.com/help/api-spec"
                         prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en-US" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:addthis="http://www.addthis.com/help/api-spec"
                         prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|(gt IEMobile 7)|!(IEMobile)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en-US" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:addthis="http://www.addthis.com/help/api-spec"
                                                                 prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>
        Budapest - Restaurant and Palinka Bar
    </title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Budapest">

    <!-- icons & favicons -->
    <!-- For iPhone 4 -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/images/icons/h/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <!-- For iPad 1-->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/images/icons/m/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <!-- For iPhone 3G, iPod Touch and Android -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/images/icons/l/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">
    <!-- For Nokia -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/images/icons/l/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <!-- For everything else -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/favicon.ico">

    <!-- media-queries.js (fallback) -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- html5.js -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <link rel="pingback" href="wp/xmlrpc.php">



    <!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast WordPress SEO plugin v1.3.4.4 - http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/ -->
    <meta name="description" content="The Budapest Hungarian Restaurant in Elsternwick offers Melbourne&#039;s best authentic Hungarian cuisine - goulash, schnitzels, cabbage rolls and palinka."/>
    <link rel="canonical" href="index.html" />
    <meta property='og:locale' content='en_US'/>
    <meta property='og:title' content='Budapest - Hungarian and European Restaurant - Elsternwick, Melbourne'/>
    <meta property='og:description' content='The Budapest Hungarian Restaurant in Elsternwick offers Melbourne&#039;s best
                                            authentic Hungarian cuisine - goulash, schnitzels, cabbage rolls and palinka.'/>
    <meta property='og:url' content='index.html'/>
    <meta property='og:site_name' content='Budapest'/>
    <meta property='og:type' content='article'/>



    <?php
        echo $this->Html->meta('icon');


        //css files from budapest.com.au
        echo $this->Html->css('app5152');
        echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap5152');
        echo $this->Html->css('responsive5152');
        echo $this->Html->css('responsive-utils5152');
        echo $this->Html->css('mj9d52');
        echo $this->Html->css('easy-fancybox.cssc412');
        echo $this->Html->css('formsa242');
        echo $this->Html->css('style5152');

        //js files from budapest.com.au
        echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min9d52');
        echo $this->Html->script('jquery.equalheights9d52');
        echo $this->Html->script('modernizr.full.min9d52');
        echo $this->Html->script('scripts9d52');
        echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.7.1.min4735');
        echo $this->Html->script('jquery.easing-1.3.pack4e44');
        echo $this->Html->script('jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.packc412');
        echo $this->Html->script('jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack459e');
        echo $this->Html->script('jquery.metadata53cf');
        echo $this->Html->script('ui.datepickera242');
        echo $this->Html->script('datepickera242');


        echo $this->fetch('meta');
        echo $this->fetch('css');
        echo $this->fetch('script');
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <div class="blackboard">
                <div id="header-top" class="hidden-phone container-fluid">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span6">
                            <a href="index.html"><img src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/logo.png" alt="Budapest Logo"></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="span6 details">
                            <p>Reservations: 03 9530 0849<br><span>Dinner 7 days: 5pm – 10pm<br>Lunch Sun: 12pm – 2:30pm</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <header class="desktop-header" role="banner" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="85">

                <div id="inner-header" class="clearfix">

                    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                        <div class="navbar-inner">
                            <div class="container-fluid nav-container">
                                <nav role="navigation">

                                    <a class="btn btn-inverse visible-phone" href="tel:03-9530-0849">03 9530 0849</a>

                                    <a class="btn pull-right btn-inverse hidden-desktop" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">Menu <i class="icon-chevron-down icon-white"></i></a>

                                    <div class="nav-collapse">
                                        <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav">
                                            <li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-6 current_page_item active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                            <li id="menu-item-109" class="dropdown hidden-phone menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About Us<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                    <li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="about-us/index.html">About Us</a></li>
                                                    <li id="menu-item-108" class="hidden-phone menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="jobs/index.html">Jobs</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>

                                            <li id="menu-item-297" class="visible-phone menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="menus-phone/index.html">Menu</a></li>
                                            <li id="menu-item-64" class="dropdown hidden-phone menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="menus/index.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menus<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                    <li id="menu-item-258" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="menus/index.html">Food and Drink</a></li>
                                                    <li id="menu-item-376" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="palinka/index.html">Pálinka</a></li>
                                                    <li id="menu-item-269" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="happy-hour/index.html">Happy Hour</a></li>
                                                    <li id="menu-item-250" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="gluten-free/index.html">Gluten Free</a></li>
                                                    <li id="menu-item-254" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="vegetarian/index.html">Vegetarian</a></li>
                                                    <li id="menu-item-395" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="passover/index.html">Passover</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>

                                            <li id="menu-item-579" class="hidden-desktop hidden-tablet menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="groupon/index.html">Groupon</a></li>
                                            <li id="menu-item-61" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="delivery/index.html">Delivery</a></li>
                                            <li id="menu-item-60" class="hidden-phone menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="gallery/index.html">Gallery</a></li>
                                            <li id="menu-item-56" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="events/index.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Events<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                    <li id="menu-item-507" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="events/index.html">Upcoming Events</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>

                                            <li id="menu-item-110" class="dropdown hidden-phone menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Functions<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                    <li id="menu-item-57" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="functions/index.html">Functions</a></li>
                                                    <li id="menu-item-603" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="fundraising/index.html">Fundraising Functions</a></li>
                                                    <li id="menu-item-113" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="schools/index.html">School Lunches</a></li>
                                                    <li id="menu-item-284" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="businessfunctions/index.html">Business Functions / Meetings</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>

                                            <li id="menu-item-59" class="hidden-phone menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="deli/index.html">Deli</a></li>
                                            <li id="menu-item-58" class="hidden-phone menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="catering/index.html">Catering</a></li>
                                            <li id="menu-item-28" class="hidden-desktop menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="contact-us/index.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                                            <li id="menu-item-305" class="hidden-desktop hidden-tablet menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="newsletter/index.html">VIP Birthday Club</a></li>
                                            <li id="menu-item-105" class="hidden-phone menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="contact/index.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                                        </ul>                                
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="pull-right hidden-phone add-this-bar">
                                        <div id="addthis-widget-2" class="widget atwidget">
                                            <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_"  >
                                                <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
                                                <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
                                                <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
                                                <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
                                                <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
                                                <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <style type='text/css'>.addthis_toolbox, .addthis_button {float:left;width:100%;margin:0 0 15px 0;} .addthis_button_tweet {min-width: 83px;float:left;}</style>                                                
                                    </div>

                                </nav>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div> <!-- end #inner-header -->

            </header> <!-- end header -->

            <div id="header-phone" class="visible-phone container-fluid">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <a href="index.html"><img src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/logo.png" alt="Budapest Logo"></a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="span12 details">
                        <p>Dinner 7 days: 5pm – 10pm<br>Lunch Sun: 12pm – 2:30pm<br>
                            <a class="map-addy" href="https://maps.google.com.au/maps?q=273+Glenhuntly+Rd+Elsternwick+VIC+3185&amp;hl=en&amp;sll=-37.860283,145.079616&amp;sspn=1.437703,2.90863&amp;hnear=273+Glen+Huntly+Rd,+Elsternwick+Victoria+3185&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A" target="_blank"><img class="pull-left" src="wp/wp-content/themes/budapest/library/img/icons/map.png" alt="map" />273 Glen Huntly Rd
                                <br>Elsternwick VIC 3185</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="span12 details">
                        <div class="visible-phone add-this-bar-phone">
                            <div id="addthis-widget-3" class="widget atwidget">
                                <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style"  ><a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a><a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a><a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a><a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a><a class="addthis_button_compact"></a><a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <style type='text/css'>.addthis_toolbox, .addthis_button {float:left;width:100%;margin:0 0 15px 0;} .addthis_button_tweet {min-width: 83px;float:left;}</style>                                                
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="span12 sidebar visible-phone">
                <div class="text-container">
                    <a class="btn btn-warning btn-block" href="javascript:void(window.open('http://bookatable.marketing4restaurants.com/book?key=27b221b8-73e5-11e2-a50a-1d3bd1648468','myWin', 'channelmode=no,directories=no,fullscreen=no,location=no,dependent=yes,menubar=no,resize=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,toolbar=no,titlebar=no,left=0,top=0,width=314px,height=426px'))"><i class="icon-white icon-calendar"></i> Book Table</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-warning btn-block coming-soon" href="#"><i class="icon-white icon-bell"></i> Order Delivery / Take Away</a>
                    <a href="https://store.triplefy.com/cart_items/new/59" class="btn btn-warning btn-block" target="_blank"><i class="icon-white icon-gift"></i> Buy Gift Voucher</a>
                    <a href="newsletter/index.html" class="btn btn-warning btn-block bottom-10"><i class="icon-white icon-star"></i> Join Our VIP Birthday Club</a>

                    <ul class="nav nav-list">
                        <li><a href="https://maps.google.com.au/maps?q=273+Glenhuntly+Rd+Elsternwick+VIC+3185&amp;hl=en&amp;sll=-37.860283,145.079616&amp;sspn=1.437703,2.90863&amp;hnear=273+Glen+Huntly+Rd,+Elsternwick+Victoria+3185&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A" target="_blank"><img src="wp/wp-content/themes/budapest/library/img/icons/map.png" alt="map" />Find us on the map</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/budapestrestaurant" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/icons/f-book.png" alt="facebook" />Find us on facebook</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/budapest273" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/icons/twitter.png" alt="twitter" />Follow us on Twitter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="video/index.html"><img src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/icons/video.png" alt="video" />Watch our TV Ad</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

        <div id="content">

            <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
            <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">

            <footer id="footer" role="contentinfo">

                <div id="inner-footer" class="clearfix container-fluid">

                    <nav class="clearfix"></nav>

                    <p class="pull-right">&nbsp;<a href="http://melbnet.com.au/" title="Web Design Melbnet">Web Design Melbnet</a></p>
                    <p class="pull-right hidden-phone"><a href="wp/wp-login.html" class="login">Login</a> | </p>
                    <p class="attribution">&copy; Budapest 2013</p>

                </div> <!-- end #inner-footer -->

            </footer> <!-- end footer -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to disable the DebugKit plugin. Or add the helper of DebugKit into $helpers array of AppController. BTW, if you use a DebugKit, delete the call of 'sql_dump' element

Comment: Sorry. Not a helper, but a 'DebugKit.Toolbar' component into array of components.

Comment: In Chrome, using dev tools, check if there are any missing files (js or css files not loaded) or any other errors in the console that maybe affecting how debug kit toolbar is being rendered

Answer (score 0):

In a high level config file, put

```
Configure::write('debug', 0);
```

This should disable it in normal circumstances. When you need to actively use it, put

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

in the view file that you're working with.